# In which scripture is Ram Ashtakam found?

Tags: shiva, rama, reference-request, vedvyas

In short, I want to know everything about Ram Ashtakam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its found in Valmiki krut Anand ramayan saar khand sarg 12

Also found in skand Puran which is as follows

> **भजे विशेषसुन्दरं समस्तपापखण्डनम् ।
> स्वभक्तचित्तरञ्जनं सदैव राममद्वयम् ॥ १ ॥**
> I pray always that Rama,who is second to none,who is especially pretty,Who cuts off all sins,And who makes the mind,Of his devotes happy.
>
> **जटाकलापशोभितं समस्तपापनाशकं ।
> स्वभक्तभीतिभञ्जनं भजेऽहं राममद्वयम् ॥ २ ॥**
> I pray always that Rama, Who is second to none, Who shines with his matted hair,Who destroys all sins,And who makes the mind,Of his devotees free from fear.
>
> **निजस्वरूपबोधकं कृपाकरं भवापहम् ।
> समं शिवं निरञ्जनं भजेऽहं राममद्वयम् ॥ ३ ॥**
> I pray always that Rama, Who is second to none, Who shows us his real self, Who is very merciful, Who destroys sorrows of life, Who considers every one equal,Who is peaceful, And who does all that is good.
>
> **सहप्रपञ्चकल्पितं ह्यनामरूपवास्तवम् ।
> निराकृतिं निरामयं भजेऽहं राममद्वयम् ॥ ४ ॥**
> I pray always that Rama, Who is second to none, Who shows the world in himself, Who is the truth without names, Who is someone without form, And who is away from sickness and pain.
>
> **निष्प्रपञ्चनिर्विकल्पनिर्मलं निरामयम् ।
> चिदेकरूपसन्ततं भजे ह राममद्वयम् ॥ ५ ॥**
> I pray always that Rama, Who is second to none, Who is away from the world, Who does not see differences, Who is crystal clear, Who does not have diseases, And who stands always as, The real form of truth.
>
> **भवाब्धिपोतरूपकं ह्यशेषदेहकल्पितम् ।
> गुणाकरं कृपाकरं भजेऽहं राममद्वयम् ॥ ६ ॥**
> I pray always that Rama, Who is second to none, Who is the ship to cross the sea of life, Who shines as all types of bodies,Who does good, And who shows mercy.
>
> **महावाक्यबोधकैर्विराजमानवाक्पदैः ।
> परं ब्रह्मसद्व्यापकं भजेऽहं राममद्वयम् ॥ ७ ॥**
> I pray always that Rama, Who is second to none, Who is so great that, He is fit to be known through, Great Vedic sayings,And who is Brahman,Which is spread everywhere.
>
> **शिवप्रदं सुखप्रदं भवच्छिदं भ्रमापहम् ।
> विराजमानदेशिकं भजेऽहं राममद्वयम् ॥ ८ ॥**
> I pray always that Rama, Who is second to none, Who grants peace, Who gives us pleasure, Who destroys the problems of life, Who avoids illusion, And who is the resplendent Guru.
>
> **रामाष्टकं पठति यस्सुखदं सुपुण्यं ।
> व्यासेन भाषितमिदं शृणुते मनुष्यः ॥ ९ ॥
>
> विद्यां श्रियं विपुलसौख्यमनन्तकीर्तिं ।
> संप्राप्य देहविलये लभते च मोक्षम् ॥ १० ॥**
> He who reads or hears this octet on rama, Which is easy to understand, Which gives rise to good deeds, Which is written by sage Vyasa, Would get knowledge, wealth,Pleasure and limitless fame, And once he leaves his body, He would also get salvation.

Comment: Hindi translations are not required. You have already added Sanskrit verses. Also please learn [formatting](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) so that it'll look more meaningful and understandable. For example, references can be quoted rather than keeping them as plane texts.

Comment: Okay, thanx for suggestions